# How to override YUI function in moodle?

Tags: yui, moodle

I need to override M.util.init_block_hider function in moodle. The reason is to override the blockicons with my custom ones. I can see piece of code inside the function, as follows:

```
Y.extend(blockhider, Y.Base, blockhider.prototype, {
    NAME : 'blockhider',
    ATTRS : {
                id : {},
                preference : {},
                iconVisible : {
                    value : M.util.image_url('t/switch_minus', 'moodle')
                },
                iconHidden : {
                    value : M.util.image_url('t/switch_plus', 'moodle')
                },
                block : {
                    setter : function(node) {
                        return Y.one(node);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

where the urls for images are stated. I want to reuse this function and override the url in my theme so that only block icons could be replaced. Any thoughts and ideas are welcome.
Here is the complete function inside /lib/javascript-static.js file:

```
M.util.init_block_hider = function(Y, config) {
  Y.use('base', 'node', function(Y) {
    M.util.block_hider = M.util.block_hider || (function(){
        var blockhider = function() {
            blockhider.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
        };
        blockhider.prototype = {
            initializer : function(config) {
                this.set('block', '#'+this.get('id'));
                var b = this.get('block'),
                    t = b.one('.title'),
                    a = null;
                if (t && (a = t.one('.block_action'))) {
                    var hide = Y.Node.create('<img class="block-hider-hide" tabindex="0" alt="'+config.tooltipVisible+'" title="'+config.tooltipVisible+'" />');
                    hide.setAttribute('src', this.get('iconVisible')).on('click', this.updateState, this, true);
                    hide.on('keypress', this.updateStateKey, this, true);
                    var show = Y.Node.create('<img class="block-hider-show" tabindex="0" alt="'+config.tooltipHidden+'" title="'+config.tooltipHidden+'" />');
                    show.setAttribute('src', this.get('iconHidden')).on('click', this.updateState, this, false);
                    show.on('keypress', this.updateStateKey, this, false);
                    a.insert(show, 0).insert(hide, 0);
                }
            },
            updateState : function(e, hide) {
                M.util.set_user_preference(this.get('preference'), hide);
                if (hide) {
                    this.get('block').addClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    this.get('block').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            },
            updateStateKey : function(e, hide) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) { //allow hide/show via enter key
                    this.updateState(this, hide);
                }
            }
        };
        Y.extend(blockhider, Y.Base, blockhider.prototype, {
            NAME : 'blockhider',
            ATTRS : {
                id : {},
                preference : {},
                iconVisible : {
                    value : M.util.image_url('t/switch_minus', 'moodle')
                },
                iconHidden : {
                    value : M.util.image_url('t/switch_plus', 'moodle')
                },
                block : {
                    setter : function(node) {
                        return Y.one(node);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return blockhider;
    })();
    new M.util.block_hider(config);
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work...then you just set the new vis/invis icon and call this.get('iconVisible') and it should chain through.

```js
Y.extend(blockhider, Y.Base, blockhider.prototype, {
    NAME : 'blockhider',
    ATTRS : {
                id : {},
                preference : {},
                iconVisible : {
                    value : M.util.image_url(this.get('visIcon'), 'moodle')
                },
                iconHidden : {
                    value : M.util.image_url(this.get('invisIcon'), 'moodle')
                },
                visIcon:{value: 't/switch_plus'},
                invisIcon:{value: 't/switch_minus'}
                block : {
                    setter : function(node) {
                        return Y.one(node);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```